# Whats these functions type name?

Tags: javascript, function, object

I am searching info about this type of functions (or objects), I don't know the name and it's difficult search about this without the name.

I want know how this works, I don't see any returns here:

```
var jo = {
    Hx: function (a, b) {
        a.splice(0, b)
    },
    oC: function (a) {
        a.reverse()
    },
    sw: function (a, b) {
        var c = a[0];
        a[0] = a[b % a.length];
        a[b] = c
    }
};
```

Later you can call these functions on this way: jo.Hx(a,c).

Comment: What specifically are you confused about? The functions don't return anything.

Comment: I want know about the name of this structure of object, I never see before :) and search infor about this.

Comment: All three functions defined here operate on the passed in array and modify that array - thus they don't need to return anything because the array that is passed in is modified.

Comment: thanks @jfriend00, I understand better this now :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an **[Object Literal](http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/object-literal/)**. You're defining a JavaScript object *on the fly*. The object is everything including the braces `{ ... }` and `Hx:`, `oC`, and `sw` are the object's exposed functions, similar to public methods.

Comment: Thanks, I need know about this name. I have this topic very clear now :)

Answer (score 2):

You are watching at a JavaScript object declaration that called `jo` which contains definitions of the following methods*:

```
Hx
oC
sw
```

You can use it like that:

```
jo j1 = new jo();

j1.ox(someArray);
```

*** Methods are actions that objects can perform.**

Answer (score 1):

Objects can have properties whose name is left to `:` and its value to the right of `:`.

A `function` need not return anything... The properties `Hx`, `oC`, `sw` are *methods* of object `jo` because they are assigned some functions as its value.
Since it doesn't return anything, it is doing *something* but still *nothing* as you don't return anything. Its redundant.

Answer (score 1):

The `:` is used when defining an object and it's properties. In your case the function is not returning anything. Also your `jo` object is containing different methods(`Hx,oC,sw`) which are not returning anything.